# How to break lines automatically in my framed section headings?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, framed

With the following code, I get this output:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{%
\tikz \node[draw=black, fill=black,rounded corners=2,inner sep=2mm]()
{\color{white}\thesection\quad #1};
}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A short title}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A very very very very very very very very very very  long title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

While I want it to be like this:
[image]
**How can I do that?**

Comment: Add the `\node` options: `text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-4mm\relax,align=justify`. CODE:`\node[draw=black, fill=black,rounded corners=2,inner sep=2mm,text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-4mm\relax,align=justify]`

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your comment, but the output is not what I wanted. Please see my second screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By tweaking your code a bit, it is possible to put the section title in a `\parbox` aligned at the top (`[t]` option). The width of the box is set to `\parboxwidth` which has two definitions depending on whether the total length of the section title is greater or less than `\textwidth`:

```
\ifdim\sectitlewidth>\totalwidth
  \def\parboxwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-\seclabelwidth-1em-4mm\relax}%
\else
  \def\parboxwidth{\dimexpr\sectitlewidth\relax}%
\fi
```

Here `\seclabelwith` is the length of the current section label; 1em is the length of a `\quad` and 4mm equals to `2*inner sep`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength{\seclabelwidth}
\newlength{\sectitlewidth}
\newlength{\totalwidth}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\settowidth{\seclabelwidth}{\thesection}%
   \settowidth{\sectitlewidth}{#1}%
   \setlength{\totalwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\seclabelwidth-1em-4mm\relax}%
    \ifdim\sectitlewidth>\totalwidth
      \def\parboxwidth{\totalwidth}%
    \else
      \def\parboxwidth{\sectitlewidth}%
    \fi
    \tikz \node[draw=black, fill=black,rounded corners=2,inner sep=2mm]
      {\color{white}\thesection\quad
        \parbox[t]{\parboxwidth}{#1}};
  }
  {1em}
  {}    

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\section{A short title}
\lipsum[11]
\section{A not so short title}
\section{A not so short short title}
\section{A very very very very very very long title}
\section{A very very very very very very very very very very  long title}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** A simpler version, using the `\titlewidth` lenght defined by `titlesec`. Thanks to Bernard here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596681/231952

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newlength{\seclabelwidth}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\settowidth{\seclabelwidth}{\thesection}%
   \settowidth{\titlewidth}{#1}%
    \ifdim\titlewidth>\dimexpr\textwidth-\seclabelwidth-1em-4mm\relax
      \setlength{\titlewidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\seclabelwidth-1em-4mm\relax}%
    \fi
    \tikz \node[draw=black, fill=black,rounded corners=2,inner sep=2mm]
      {\color{white}\thesection\quad
        \parbox[t]{\titlewidth}{#1}};
  }
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\section{A short title}
\lipsum[11]
\section{A not so short title}
\section{A not so short short title}
\section{A very very very very very veryee long title}
\section{A very very very very very very very very very very  long title}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your output is not what I wanted again! Please see my first section (A short title).

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer. However, I suspect there is a more elegant solution