# LaTeX dynamic \rule width depending on text length with titleformat

Tags: sectioning, rules, textwidth

I have a section divider as below:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{F8CBAD}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{D9D9D9}

\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
  }{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-5pt}\color{pink}\rule{5cm}{0.7mm} \color{grey}\rule{13.3cm}{0.7mm}]

\begin{document}
  \section{Research Interests}
  ...
  \section{Selected Courses and Grades}
\end{document}
```

which gives me output like this:
[image]

### What I need?

I want to specify the length of the pink line exactly as the text above it, coming from `titleformat`. and the grey line takes the rest of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure the text and use this length. The only complication is that this setting should be global.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{F8CBAD}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{D9D9D9}

\titleformat{\section}
 {\large\scshape\filright}
 {}
 {0em}
 {\makesectiontitle}
 [%
  \vspace{-5pt}%
  \color{pink}\rule{\sectiontitlewd}{0.7mm}\hspace{0.33333em}%
  \color{grey}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\sectiontitlewd-0.33333em}{0.7mm}%
 ]
\newlength{\sectiontitlewd}
\newcommand{\makesectiontitle}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \global\sectiontitlewd=\dimen0
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Research Interests}
  ...
  \section{Selected Courses and Grades}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for contributing. can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with the `calcwidth` option of titlesec:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{F8CBAD}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{D9D9D9}

\titleformat{\section}{\scshape\raggedright\large}{}{0em}{}%
[\color{pink}{\rule[7pt]{\titlewidth}{0.7mm}}\color{grey}{\rule[7pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\titlewidth}{0.7mm}}]

\begin{document}

  \section{Research Interests}

The Clangle-Wangle

  \section{Selected Courses and Grades}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for contributing. can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{F8CBAD}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{D9D9D9}

\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
  }{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-5pt}\color{pink}\rule{\wd8}{0.7mm}\color{grey}%
  \rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd8}{0.7mm}]

\let\svsection\section
\renewcommand\section[2][\relax]{%
  \sbox8{\large\textsc{#2}}%
  \ifx\relax#1\def\next{\svsection}%
  \else\def\next{\svsection[#1]}%
  \fi\next{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Research Interests}
  ...
  \section{Selected Courses and Grades}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for contributing. can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation

Comment: No worry. I only post for helping.